# How to host Django website using cPanel?

Tags: django, apache, cpanel, mod-wsgi

I am new to the world of website hosting, especially in cPanel platform. I have a website which is developed using Python language, which makes use of Django also. I have hosted this website in cPanel. But it doesn't seems to be working.

When I browse my website domain (www.def.com), now it displays site.wsgi (wsgi file) file as such.

I could know that by default, CPanel doesn't support Django. Using SSH, I have installed Django. But I am not sure how to configure the same. Would be good if I can get a step by step instructions on how to install and configure Django in cPanel.

FYI, This is a shared web hosting server from GoDaddy and that too not a virtual Private server or doesn't have root access. How will host this site by using wsgi file.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems CPanel does not support Django apps "out of the box", google results lead me to believe [it might be possible using a more manual method](http://server-support.co/blog/sysadmin/django-on-cpanel-server-for-shared-web-hosting/).

Additionally, CPanel has [this plugin for Django/python installation](http://applications.cpanel.net/appcat/admin-ahead-django-plugin-for-cpanel)

Please note that I have not tried any of the above, but the latter seems more promising since it has been updated more recently (2015, as opposed to the 2011 blog entry).

Comment: ok thanks,reference was good.Can you please suggest me some hosting services where its is easy and cheaper to host a django website

Comment: My own preference is to use a "free" hosting for projects under development, and if the need arises "pay for more". Both [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) and [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) offer a free easy minimal hosting for your python/django apps and you can always pay up to scale it up.